# NSTableView Binding and Observers

Tags: cocoa, model-view-controller, nstableview, key-value-observing

I am trying to add a new row to an NSTableview using bindings. According to a past post I was instructed to addObject on the array controller and the KVO should handle the notification to the view. However,

I get the following error:

```
An -observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context: message was received but not handled.
Key path: accountArray
    Observed object: <AppDelegate: 0x10011e3b0>
Change: {
     indexes = "<NSIndexSet: 0x102915ba0>[number of indexes: 1 (in 1 ranges), indexes: (2)]";
     kind = 2;
}
```

I have added this observer in my App Delegate:

```
[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"accountArray" options:0 context:@"myContext"];
```

I have also tried to implement the observerValueforKeyPath but when I debug my code never gets to this point.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You must implement that method:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
```

Comment: I'm still new to KVO but what I ended up doing was creating an IBOutlet for my add button and implementing the addition of a new object in my NSMutable array. I then implemented [self willchangeValueforKey] and [self didChangeValueForKey] and everything seemed to work. I'm not sure why but could it be because my arrayController is already KVO compliant?